# Is there a way to convert excel to csv in python 2.6?

Tags: python, excel, pip, export-to-csv, python-2.6

Currently, I have a 2.6 version of python on my windows machine.
I intended to use *pandas*, *xlrd*, and *openpyxl* for excel parsing, but since pip is not installed automatically in v2.6, I tried to install it manually, but pip has discontinued its services to 2.6 python, and I was unable to install any package file required to parse excel.
Is it possible to convert Excel to CSV in python 2.6?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't install a more modern version of Python? Version 2.6 is more than 13 years old, there are *very good* reasons it's not supported any more.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.